# CSS: How can I border a div, keeping it entirely inside another div?

Tags: html, css

I think this should be a simple task: I want to put one bordered div inside of another (non-bordered) div, so that the inner div stays completely inside the outer div.  In other words, the contents of the inner div should resize to be 100% the size of the outer div, minus twice the inner div's border size. As an example, consider this HTML ([or JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kqc79z44/)):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outlined"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

With these styles:

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width:  20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.outlined {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    background-color: green;
    width:  100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
```

This yields this:

[image]

But I'm trying to get this:

[image]

(Disregard the size of the grey background, that's just my inconsistent screenshotting)

Any ideas?  I know I could set the width and height of the inner div manually to the correct number of pixels, but I'd rather not do that if it can be avoided, since it adds another thing to remember any time I resize the outer div.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.outlined` so that it's borders are contained within the specified height/width.

```css
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.outlined {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    background-color: green;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="outlined"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
</div>
```

Comment: @ChristopherShroba np!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a calc expression

```css
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.outlined {
    border: 3px solid blue;
    background-color: green;
    width: calc(100% - 6px);
    height:calc(100% - 6px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="outlined"></div>
</div>

<div class="container">
</div>
```